# Is it possible to make python input() stick to bottom of console window while other processes print output?

Tags: python, command-line-interface, curses

Given a background process that is constantly printing to stddout, is there a way to make the call to `input()` "stick" to the bottom of the console?

```py
import time
import multiprocessing


def print_in_background():
    x = 0
    while True:
        print(f'Background print {x}')
        x += 1
        time.sleep(1)

def get_input():
    return input('> ')

background_proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=print_in_background)
background_proc.daemon = True
background_proc.start()
while True:
    v = get_input()
    print(v)
background_proc.join()
```

This works in that you can have the background thread do stuff while the main thread gets input, but the output looks like this, where the `input()` line gets pushed up by the background process's output:

```
> Background print 0
Background print 1
Background print 2
I am Background print 3
typingBackground print 4

I am typing
> Background print 5
Background print 6
```

Theoretically, output like this would be preferable:

```
Background print 0
Background print 1
Background print 2
Background print 3
Background print 4
I am typing          # From when user hit enter key
Background print 5
Background print 6
> typing in current prompt
```

If possible, making the input prompt stay on the bottom line of the console would be optimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the Curses library in Python stdlib to create two windows: one for output and one that had a textbox that the user can type into.